# RPostgreSQL installation Error - RPostgreSQL.so: undefined symbol: PQpass

Tags: r, centos, rpostgresql

I am trying to install R-Package RPostgreSQL, but getting the following error,

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/RPostgreSQL/libs/RPostgreSQL.so':
  /usr/lib64/R/library/RPostgreSQL/libs/RPostgreSQL.so: undefined symbol: PQpass
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/RPostgreSQL’
```

I have `libpq` and `postgresql-dev` installed. All the library files are in the directory

`/usr/lib64/pgsql/` and all header files are in the directory

`/usr/include/pgsql/`

Postgre Version - `9.3.4`
R Version - `3.0.2`
Operating System - `CentOS-6.4`

I am missing some small thing, but unable to find out why this is happening.

What am I doing wrong? How to correct this?

Comment: I'd say the `libpq.so` being found is different to the one that `RPostgreSQL.so` was originally linked to. `ldd /usr/lib64/R/library/RPostgreSQL/libs/RPostgreSQL.so` please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package RPostgreSQL checks for PostgreSQL libraries only in the following directory paths,

```
    /usr/lib 
/usr/lib/pgsql 
/usr/lib/postgresql 
/usr/local/lib 
/usr/local/lib/pgsql 
/usr/local/lib/postgresql 
/usr/local/pgsql/lib 
/usr/local/postgresql/lib 
/opt/lib 
/opt/lib/pgsql 
/opt/lib/postgresql 
/opt/local/lib 
/opt/local/lib/postgresql 
/opt/local/lib/postgresql84 
/sw/opt/postgresql-8.4/lib 
/Library/PostgresPlus/8.4SS/lib 
/sw/lib
```

It does not check for the directories either in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

So RPostgreSQL installation will be successful only if the PostgreSQL libraries exist in any of the above directories.

When I copied the libraries from `/usr/lib64/pgsql` to `/usr/lib/pgsql` and tried installing the package. It worked. :)

Comment: Your answer helped me get it installed.  But inspecting the configure file in package, it turns out that it first checks `pg_config --libdir`.  All I needed to do was make sure `pg_config` was visible in `PATH`.

Comment: @user1071847 Could you explain how to make pg_config visible in PATH?

Comment: @Andy:  (This is for Linux.)  In my `.bash_profile` file, I edited `PATH` to be `PATH=$HOME/bin:$HOME/usr/bin:$HOME/usr/local/pgsql/bin:$PATH`.  You'd have to replace `$HOME/usr/local/pgsql/bin` by whatever the path to `pg_config` is in your case, and of course all the other path components other than the last are for my setup only.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the pgsql libraries are no longer installed in their previous locations. I linked both:

```
ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib /usr/lib/pgsql

ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.3/include /usr/include/pgsql
```

This worked for me :)