# error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory when running rust app

Tags: docker, rust

To reduce the docker image size, I package my rust app as an docker image like this:

```
# build stage
FROM rust:1.54 as builder
LABEL maintainer="jiangtingqiang@gmail.com"
ENV ROCKET_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
ENV ROCKET_PORT=11014
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN rustup default stable
RUN cargo build --release

# Prod stage
FROM gcr.io/distroless/cc
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/reddwarf_music /
CMD ["./reddwarf_music"]
```

but when I start the docker image in kubernetes cluster, the pod log shows that:`./reddwarf_music: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, To my understand the rust compiled app was  independent and do not need any third party library, why would this happen? what should I do to fix this problem? I have searching from internet but no one facing this problem. My app was an web api server, and using PostgreSQL 13 as my backend database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finnaly tweak the dockerfile like this:

```
# build stage
FROM rust:1.54-bullseye as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN rustup default stable
RUN cargo build --release

# Prod stage
FROM debian:bullseye-slim
LABEL maintainer="jiangtingqiang@gmail.com"
ENV ROCKET_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
ENV ROCKET_PORT=11014
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install postgresql -y
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/reddwarf_music /
CMD ["./reddwarf_music"]
```

the image size from `1GB+` to `100MB+`, the max layer was `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install postgresql -y`, it take more than 100MB, I have to install the postgresql because the rust diesel need using the lib `libpq.so.5` from postgresql. The key to fix the error was install postgresql. I did not know any better way to fix this problem.

Improve:

we can change postgresql to libpq5 like this:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libpq5 -y
```

only take 40MB+.

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to use the same os image base, for example:

```
FROM rust:1.54-bullseye-slim as builder
# ...
FROM debian:bullseye-slim
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I was setting up a Dockerfile for Actix Web, Diesel and Postgres. But it shouldn't matter since the real problem actually lies with `diesel` and `postgres` instead.

Supposed we have a multistage build like your setup above, in the second stage (based on distroless image), we need to copy the related `libpq` files over from the previous build stage.

Something like the following

```
# ---------------------------------------------------
# 2 - Deploy Stage
#
# Use a distroless image for minimal container size
# - Copy `libpq` dependencies into the image (Required by diesel)
# - Copy application files into the image
# ---------------------------------------------------
FROM gcr.io/distroless/cc-debian11

# Set the architecture argument (arm64, i.e. aarch64 as default)
# For amd64, i.e. x86_64, you can append a flag when invoking the build `... --build-arg "ARCH=x86_64"`
ARG ARCH=aarch64

# libpq related (required by diesel)
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libpq.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libidn2.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libunistring.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libnettle.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libgmp.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libffi.so* /usr/lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so* /lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build /lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so* /lib/${ARCH}-linux-gnu/

# Application files
COPY --from=build /usr/local/cargo/bin/codefee-works-api /usr/local/bin/codefee-works-api
COPY --from=build /usr/src/codefee-works-api/.env /.env
```

Notice that I set a default value here for `ARG ARCH=aarch64`. That is because I am on an `arm64` architecture machine, e.g. M1 Mac. If you happen to be on an `amd64`, i.e. `x86_64` machine, you can set it to `ARG ARCH=x86_64` instead. Or simply have the build argument value passed in upon running the Docker build command.

I have written an in-depth article on this topic. You can find out more over here https://www.codefeetime.com/post/docker-config-for-actix-web-diesel-and-postgres#32-resolving-missing-lib-dependencies